# Analog clock - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clock

I read a code for an analog clock, and its JavaScript contain this:

```
  clockElement.style.setProperty("--seconds", offset + 6 * seconds + "deg");
  clockElement.style.setProperty("--hours", offset + 30 * hours + "deg");
  clockElement.style.setProperty("--minutes", offset + 6 * minutes + "deg");
```

I understand the meaning/value except the "deg" part. It's not mentioned anywhere else but between those parenthesis. 
**edit:**
The offset value is -90
What I mean with "deg" is...it doesn't hold any value. For example, the CSS looks like this:

```
#analogClock .second {
transform: rotate(var(--seconds));
}
```

So, where does the degree come from?

Comment: Go to the setProperty method and see what it does! :)

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, variables are declared like this:

```css
--my-variable: 20px;
```

and used like this:

```css
height: var(--my-variable);
```

(You can learn more about CSS variables [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp))

So essentially what this does is add a CSS variable, so it can be used later in the CSS, for example:

```css
#clock {
   --angle: 0deg;
   transform: rotate(var(--angle));
}
```

But you want the clock to move, so at a set time, JavaScript updates the value of the variable, causing the hands to move.

Answer (score 0):

It's angle value in CSS [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/angle)

if `offset` is 0 (not clear from your code snippet what it is used for), and `seconds` is 30 - then the first statement sets property to `"180deg"` (probably, arrow down as you would expect for 30 seconds)